# Error al insertar un datetime con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy cambiando todo el sistema de `Mysqli` a `PDO` y estoy teniendo un problema al intentar insertar una fecha en un campo de un registro. El registro que intento grabar es una noticia, que involucra una fecha. El formato de la fecha que traigo con el `POST` es del tipo "`2017-07-26 20:52`" y esa fecha y hora se toma automáticamente por el sistema. Mientras usaba `mysqli` no tenía problemas para grabar los registros.

```
$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("INSERT INTO noticias (fecha, titulo, resumen, texto, vigente, 
cant_lecturas) VALUES (':fecha', ':titulo', ':sResumen', ':sTexto', ':vigente', 
':cant_lecturas')");
$stmt->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha);
$stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
$stmt->bindParam(':sResumen', $sResumen);
$stmt->bindParam(':sTexto', $sTexto);
$stmt->bindParam(':vigente', $vigente);
$stmt->bindParam(':cant_lecturas', $cant_lecturas);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $resultado = 1;
} else {
    $resultado = null;
}
```

Al Ejecutar el proceso de inserción me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 
1292 Incorrect datetime value: ':fecha' for column 'fecha' at row 1'
```

¿Qué podrá ser?

Comment: En la consulta SQL no debes encerrar los parámetros con comillas simples. Creo que el campo fecha queda así: `'"2017-01-01"'` y por eso el error dice formato de fecha inválido.

Comment: decis en la definicion de los VALUES ? estaban sin comillas y tiraba el mismo error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error se debe a que cuando usas consultas preparadas, los marcadores de nombre no deben ir rodeados de comillas:

<s>':fecha', ':titulo', ':sResumen', ':sTexto', ':vigente'...</s>

En cuanto a la falta de los segundos en la cadena: `2017-07-26 20:52` hice una prueba en phpfiddle y PDO agrega dos ceros cuando faltan los segundos.

De todos modos, si quieres, puedes construir tu fecha desde la cadena recibida usando la clase `DateTime`, aunque no es necesario, ya que el código funciona sin los segundos.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d6z8-n7s1)

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

/**
 *  Creamos una tabla de prueba 
*/

$sql="CREATE TABLE test_date (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    dt DATETIME
);";
$pdo->query($sql);

/**
 *  Borramos e  insertamos  datos de prueba
 *  ¡Cuidado!  no  uses DELETE  en un  escenario  real
*/

$sql="DELETE FROM test_date";
$pdo->query($sql);

$nombre="Pedro";
$fecha="2017-07-26 20:52";

$sql="INSERT INTO  test_date (nombre,  dt)  VALUES (:nombre, :dt)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
$stmt->bindValue(":dt",$fecha);
$stmt->execute();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_date";   

$arrDatos = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS\n";
    print_r($arrDatos);    
    echo "</pre>";


}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}

$pdo = null;

?>
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  1 REGISTROS

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [nombre] => Pedro
            [dt] => 2017-07-26 20:52:00
        )

)
```

Comment: Hola, estuve viendo el desarrollo de cómo planteas la idea, pero no se por que a mi no me funciona. Primero intenté adaptarlo a mi problema, y no funcionó y deje un espacio en la página y copie literalmente el ejemplo y en la tabla test_date NO GRABA LOS REGISTROS y el error que arrojaba en mi sector del codigo ahora sale en la linea donde dice: $stmt->bindValue(":dt",$fecha);

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-07-27 09:13 ' for column 'dt' at row 1'

Comment: @MNibor ¿No será que te esta dando problemas el espacio que esta justo despues de los minutos?

Comment: ya detecte donde esta el problema... el $_POST['fecha'] lo tengo que reconvertir a formato fecha pero por alguna razón no me toma la fecha actual y me pone una fecha del año 1970...

Comment: @MNibor probando con el fiddle, si intento insertar una fecha **con un espacio en blanco al final**, el código funciona, pero inserta esto : `[dt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Visto desde otro punto de vista. Sería importante tener una función que _limpie_ tus datos, que controle que estos no sean erróneos indicando mensajes al usuario. Por ejemplo, controlar que no haya espacios en blanco al final, que no haya dobles o triples espacios en blanco. En el caso de fechas, construir un objeto fecha, etc. No obstante, como muestra el fiddle, el código debería funcionar sin ese espacio al final.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente solo te falta agregar los segundos:

```
$fecha .= ':00';
```

Entonces, fecha quedará como: "2017-07-26 20:52:00".

Si todavía te quedan dudas, revisa la documentación de MySQL: **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html**

Comment: los segundos se agregaban solos en msqli asi que supongo que en PDO debe suceder lo mismo... sigo con el mismo problema asi que no se cómo resolverlo

Comment: El mensaje que obtienes especifica que es un error de formato en campo datetime y no veo otra posible solución.

Por el momento no puedo comentar en otras respuestas, pero te guarda 1970-01-01 00:01:00 porque es la fecha por default y, si vas a usar date(), asegúrate de convertir $_POST['fecha'] en timestamp, usando strtotime()

Comment: $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:m', strtotime($_POST['fecha']));  asi ?

Comment: ¿Por qué no agregar los segundos y olvidarte del problema?

$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime($_POST['fecha']));

Comment: si, también... por que no ? ahora se lo agrego...

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una solución parcial y digo parcial porque guardó cualquier fecha pero grabó el registro. Se me ocurrió convertir a date la variable $fecha haciendo:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:m', $_POST['fecha']);
```

el único problema que encontré es que el valor de fecha y hora que me tomó fue

```
1970-01-01 00:01:00
```

lo cual es un misterio... pero bueno, logré que grabe en la base de datos...

Comment: Creo que debes revisar tu configuración de PHP, ya que son varias las preguntas en las que planteas situaciones que funcionan en condiciones normales, pero en tu caso no. Este mismo es un ejemplo, como he mostrado en mi respuesta. Por cierto, todas esas preguntas van quedando abiertas, sin solución marcada. ¿No tendrás algún problema en tu configuración de PHP?